# webRTC - the video and audio stream is interrupted after 40 seconds when the connection is established via the mobile network

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn

When I stream video-audio of both users on the same or different cable network, there is no problem, everyone can see, listen, etc. When one user is on the mobile network and the other on the cable (the user on the cable creates the call), there is no problem. The problem is when the devices are on the same or different mobile networks, after about 30 seconds the picture freezes and the sound stops (the call is made from the mobile network). Note that I also have my own STUN/TURN server which I test and it does not give any errors. Does anyone know how to fix this? Where can the error be generated?